# Regex to match only part that has no following multiple whitespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have some text which is left and right centered on the screen and looks like this

```
From:
DEMO - Sliced Invoices                                            Order Number
Suite 5A-1204                          Order Number
123 Somewhere Street                  Order Number
Your City AZ 12345                      Order Number
admin@slicedinvoices.com                  Order Number
```

What i am trying to achieve is write a regex to only get the left parts ignoring the Order Number part which can be any text not specifically Order Number... Is that even possible i tried ignoring multiple white spaces with no luck.

So far i've come up with this:

```
F.{1,250}?:+\nD.{1,250}?
```

Which reads

```
From:
Demo - Sliced Invoices
```

But i can't continue to the next line because of the Order Number being on the same line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
^.*?(?=\s{2,}|\n)
```

- `^` - start of string
- `.+?` - Match anything except new line zero or more time
- `(?=\s{2,}|\n)` - Positive lookahed to check two or more continues space or newline

```js
let str = `From:
DEMO - Sliced Invoices                                            Order Number
Suite 5A-1204                          Order Number
123 Somewhere Street                  Order Number
Your City AZ 12345                      Order Number
admin@slicedinvoices.com                  Order Number`

let op = str.match(/^.+?(?=\s{2,}|\n)/gm)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures everything up to two or more spaces, or a line break using a [lookahead](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/the-complicated-syntax-of-lookaheads-in-javascript-regular-expressions/).

```js
const regex = /^(.*?)(?= {2,}|\n)/gm;
const txt = document.querySelector('div').textContent;
const matches = txt.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<div>From:
DEMO - Sliced Invoices                                            Order Number
Suite 5A-1204                          Order Number
123 Somewhere Street                  Order Number
Your City AZ 12345                      Order Number
admin@slicedinvoices.com                  Order Number</div>
```